# Why am I getting error code 135 when applying patch through opatch?

Tags: oracle, command-line, middleware, patch

I am trying to write a script that automates opatch, but before I get into the actual scripting I want to test the commands directly through the command prompt. My oracle home is C:\oracle\Middleware, and my patch 23094292 folder is located in the Middleware folder. Here are the commands I am using to apply the patch:

```
cd C:\oracle\Middleware\23094292
C:\oracle\Middleware\OPatch\opatch apply
```

When I run the latter command I get this:

**ZOP-51: The patch location is not valid for apply, because it doesn't have correct metadata, or it points to a patch directory.
Argument(s) Error... Patch location is not valid for apply
Please check the arguments and try again.
OPatch failed with error code = 135**

Shouldn't oracle home be the valid patch location? I am not too familiar with Oracle's product's, so I'm not certain. Please let me know if I can provide any further information. Any help explaining what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the contents of the 23094292 directory?

Comment: Also, make sure you have an ORACLE_HOME variable set that points to the C:\oracle\Middleware directory.

Comment: Updated with screenshots. When I run lsinventory it says oracle home is set to C:\oracle\MIDDLE~1, but in the registry editor it says it's C:\oracle\Middleware.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a directory in the 23094292 directory. There should be two directories in there, "files" and "etc". And then there should be a "README.txt" file there as well.

Edit: I'd just suggest removing the 23094292 directory and unzipping the zip file again, or re-download it if that doesn't work.

Comment: It seems the zip file didn't come with an etc folder, however, I notice that I have the older smart update utility installed as well. Could that be affecting anything?

Comment: It's not going to affect the fact that you're missing files from your quarterly patch zip. That's the main problem that you have. Smart update is not used with Weblogic 12.1.3, opatch is, so you're doing it right.